# Differential in Polar coordinates (velocity)

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

The velocity of circular motion in polar coordinates is like this;
$$\vec v(t) = \frac{d}{dt}\vec r(t) = \frac{dR}{dt} \hat u_R (t)\ +\ R \frac{d\hat u_R}{dt} $$ 
where $R$ is the radius, and $\hat u_R (t)$ is unit vector parallel to the radius.

Why the differential is different? I want to know how to split $\frac {d}{dt}\vec r(t)$ to 
$$\frac{d}{dt}\vec r(t) = \frac{dR}{dt} \hat u_R (t)\ +\ R \frac{d\hat u_R}{dt} $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood you right. Write $\vec{r}(t)=R(t)\hat{u}_R(t)$ and apply the product formula for differentials. This explaines the equation. The 'problem' with your notation is that you omit the $t$-dependency of $R$ and $\hat{u}_R$. A more complete expression would be:
\begin{align}
 \frac{d}{dt} \vec{r}(t) = \frac{d}{dt}(R(t) \cdot \hat{u}_R(t)) = \frac{d}{dt}(R(t)) \cdot \hat{u}_R(t) + R(t) \cdot \frac{d}{dt}(\hat{u}_R(t))
\end{align}

Comment: Oh! is $R$ also depend on $t$? Then, is it okay to understand the equation as the Product Rule?

Comment: Yes. If you picture $r(t)=R\cdot \hat{u}_R(t)$, you will see that $R$ has to be $t$-dependend. Otherwise you could only move around with constant distance $R$ to the origin.